# Are there wildcards for BCP?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to run a command script that executes a BCP utility. I want it to be able to find any files with a specific file name format, for example, fileyyyymmdd.dat.  Is there any way of replacing the yyyymmdd with wildcards, like a ? or * in other programs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not in bcp, but you could use a PowerShell script or other command scripting outside of BCP.